# Nth K-Ugly Number

Tags: code-golf, math, primes, number-theory

Write the shortest code in any language of your choice to find the \$N\$th \$K\$-ugly number.

A \$K\$-ugly number is a number whose only prime factors are the prime numbers \$\le K\$.
\$K\$-ugly number's are popularly known as \$K\$-smooth numbers.

Constraints:

- \$0 < N < 1000\$
- \$0 < K < 25\$

Input:

- `N K` (separated by a single space)

Output:

- `-1` (if no such number exists)
  *or*
- \$M\$ (if \$N\$th \$K\$-ugly number is \$M\$)

Comment: These numbers are usually referred to as [k-smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).

Comment: @primo hahaha.. thats funny. I never knew about k-smooth

Comment: You should exclude `k=1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600048/nth-ugly-number/4600082#4600082

Comment: @DavidCarraher Well, the objective is quite different and thus I think it is fine.

Comment: I now see that the present problem is of a more general nature.

Comment: May we assume a largest output? For example _N=1000, K=2_ gives _5.357543 x 10^300_.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <s>82 72</s> 70

```
n_~u~k_:=(c=m=1;While[m <= n,If[FactorInteger[c][[-1,1]]<=k,m++];c++];c-1)
```

**Usage**

```
u[1, 5]
u[5, 2]
u[20, 3]
u[57, 5]
u[66, 13]
u[100, 5]
u[1000, 25]
```

> 1
> 16
> 96
> 324
> 110
> 1536
> 5474

---

Prime factors and their powers are in the center column.

```
Table[{t, FactorInteger[t], u[t, 5]}, {t, 15}] // Grid
```

[image: data]

Comment: `n_~u~k_:=` OMG! you made my day :)

Comment: `c=1;m=1;` can be replaced with `c=m=1;`

Comment: @alephalpha Yes. Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2 - 63 bytes

```
i=t=1
n,k=input()
while~-n:i+=1;t*=i>k or i**n;n-=t%i<1
print i
```

Input is taken from stdin, comma separated.

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 1, 5 | python nth-k-smooth.py
1

$ echo 5, 2 | python nth-k-smooth.py
16

$ echo 20, 3 | python nth-k-smooth.py
96

$ echo 57, 5 | python nth-k-smooth.py
324

$ echo 66, 13 | python nth-k-smooth.py
110

$ echo 100, 5 | python nth-k-smooth.py
1536

$ echo 1000, 25 | python nth-k-smooth.py
5474
```

---

At *N = 1000*, the script has a reasonable execution time for all values *K ≥ 7*. For the input *N = 1000, K = 2* the correct answer is *2<sup>999</sup> ≈ 5.357543300·10<sup>300</sup>*. Using an "increase by one" approach, as [David Carraher's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12889) also does, it would take longer than the age of the universe to reach this value (considerably longer!).

Comment: syntax error at "n,k=input()"

Comment: The script is written for Python 2.

Comment: mine is Python 2.7.3, shouldn't it work? i m noob :)

Comment: My version is also 2.7.3. Are you sure you're receiving a `Syntax Error` and not `EOF Error`? If not run interactively, you will need to supply input via stdin, as in the usage examples above.

Comment: my mistake, its EOF error. I assumed your input is single space separated n and k as specified in the problem.

Comment: Hah.  This is shorter than the sage solution I'd come up with, using built-ins... problem being that they've got lotsa letters to be user-friendly: `x.prime_divisors()`... ugh

Comment: you never use that `j`

Comment: You're right... it was the counting variable for a loop which is no longer there. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### APL(Dyalog), 38

```
{⍵≡1:¯1⋄⊃⌽⍺{0~⍨⍺↑y[⍋y←∪,⍵∘.×⍵]}⍣≡⍳⍵}/⎕
```

Finally, for once, APL has beaten GS!!

---

**Sample**

```
⎕:
      5 3
6

⎕:
      20 5
36

⎕:
      500 20
2028

⎕:
      50 1
¯1
```

---

**Explanation**

`/⎕` Takes evaluated input (space-seperated numbers are interpreted as numerical array) and insert a function in between (reduce).

`⍵≡1:` If right argument (k) is 1
`¯1` return -1 (`¯` is the high-minus, APL's way of representing negative numbers)
`⋄` Statement seperator used as `else`.

`⍳⍵` Generate a numerical array from 1 to k
`⍺{...}⍣≡` Recursively apply function until output of an iteration is the same as that of the last iteration (fixpoint), passing the left argument of outer function (N) as the left each iteration.

`⍵∘.×⍵` Outer product of the left argument with itself (generating a multiplication table)
`,` Unravel the matrix to numerical array
`∪` Remove duplicates
`y[⍋y←...]` Sort
`⍺↑` Get the first N values (fills 0s if shorter than N)
`0~⍨` Remove 0s
**In short, `⍺{0~⍨⍺↑y[⍋y←∪,⍵∘.×⍵]}⍣≡⍳⍵` generates the first N k-smooth numbers**

`⊃⌽` get last value

Answer (score 2):

### R 133 characters

```
a=scan(n=2)
k=1:a[2]
i=m=0
while(m<a[1]){i=i+1;if(all(sfsmisc::factorize(i)[[1]][,1]%in%k[rowSums(!outer(k,k,`%%`))<3]))m=m+1}
cat(i)
```

Explanation:

`` k[rowSums(!outer(k,k,`%%`))<3] ``: k being here the sequence from 1 to K, this piece of code outputs the list of primes smaller or equal to K.
`` all(sfsmisc::factorize(i)[[1]][,1]%in%k[rowSums(!outer(k,k,`%%`))<3]) ``: this checks that all of the primes used to factorize a number belong to the previous list. It uses a function from package `sfsmisc` that performs the prime factorization.

Comment: these brackets around `m=m+1` are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript, 42 characters

```
~),2>{:s,2>{s\%!},!},:^1+1+{$({*}+^%|}@*0=
```

Unfortunately, I had to insert several correction terms to get the indexing correct.

Examples:

```
> 5 2
16

> 20 3
96

> 66 13
110

> 1000 25
5474
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 96 characters

```
{n,k}=%~Read~{Number,Number};If[n>k==1,-1,While[p<n,m++;If[Max@FactorInteger[m][[All,1]]<=k,p++]];m]
```

Ungolfed:

```
{n, k} = % ~Read~ {Number, Number};
If[n > k == 1,
  -1, 
  While[p < n, 
    m++; 
    If[Max@FactorInteger[m][[All, 1]] <= k, p++]
  ]; m
]
```

I did manage to find a shorter solution, more in the spirit of Mathematica's functional programming style by avoiding the while-loop, but it runs out of memory without an upper bound on *M*. It also cheats on the space-seperated input, but I thought it was elegant (60 characters):

```
Select[Range@999,Max@FactorInteger[#][[All,1]]<=k&][[n]]~Check~-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 1.9+, 101 chars

Sort of verbose but nice and functional:

```
require'Prime'
n,k=gets.split.map &:to_i
p (1..5474).select{|i|i.prime_division.all?{|j,l|j<=k}}[n-1]
```

edit:

The number constant `5474` represents the highest value the program will ever output (upper bound), and is the answer to *N = 1000, K = 2*. As Primo points out, this may be a little low.

If you for some reason would like to run this program, the upper bound can be changed to whatever you want. Increasing it by a few digits will however increase execution time dramatically<sup>[1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12896/4372)</sup>, even for small outputs.

A feature I find quite neat is that the program cleanly outputs `nil` if the output would exceed the upper bound.

Comment: _5474_ (the result of _N = 1000, K = 23-28_) as an upper bound might be a bit low. For example, _N = 1000, K = 7 -> 385875_.

Comment: @primo I totally agree. Added some clarification.